# How do I set the event source type aka. trigger with AWS.Lambda createFunction

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

How do I set the trigger type aka. event source type (like Alexa Skill Kit, etc) with AWS.Lambda in the node.js aws-sdk? I can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#createEventSourceMapping-property)

Comment: I got this far, but it seems to take only Dynamo and Kinesis stream arns. What about the rest you can set on the UI? Like Alexa skills?